# Двузонный или двухзонный?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте!

"Запнулась" о слово: двузонный или двухзонный? Речь идет о климат-контроле в автомобиле. Буду признательна за помощь (если возможно, то с отсылкой к правилу).

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Равноправны оба варианта написания слова: двузонный=двухзонный.

Равноправны варианты сложных слов, в состав которых входит элемент: дву- – двух-, например: двуголосный – двухголосный, двудонный – двухдонный, двуклассный – двухклассный, двулетний – двухлетний, двупольный – двухпольный, двускатный – двухскатный, двусложный – двухсложный, двустволка – двухстволка, двусторонность – двухсторонность.
Сложные слова двубортный, двуглавый, двугривенный, двуединый, двужильный, двузначный, двузубец, двуколка, двукратный, двуличный, двуперстие, двурогий, двусмысленный, двустопный, двууглекислый, двучлен, двуязычный и некоторые др. не допускают вариантов написания с двух-.
Но основной массив таких сложных слов пишется с элементом двух-: двухатомный, двухгодичный, двухкамерный, двухлетие, двухместный, двухпалубный, двухпроцентный, двухслойный, двухсотлетний, двухсуточный, двухтактный, двухтомный, двухчасовой, двухцветный, двухэтажный и др.
Разграничительную роль играет фонетико-орфоэпическое отличие: перед гласными (в том числе йотированными), как правило, употребляется двух- во избежание стечения двух гласных, например: двухактный, двухосный, двухъярусный, двухэлементный, но имеются отступления: двуокись, двууглекислый, двуязычие и некоторые др.

Справочник Розенталя, §168. Числительные в составе сложных слов
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

Comment: Матвей, спасибо за развернутый ответ! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: _**Розенталь: Сложные слова... двузначный…  двустопный…  не допускают вариантов написания с двух-**_.
Допускают. См. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x; http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Answer (score 5):

В текстах мне встретилась только одна форма написания  -  **двухзонный**, в том числе **двухзонный климат-контроль.** Возможно, это связано с тем, что числительное два здесь имеет **прямое значение**:  сейчас появились такие устройства, как  трех- или даже четырехзонный климат-контроль.

**Пояснение**

(1) В большинстве сложных слов используется форма ДВУХ, которая характерна для **прямого значения**  числительного два, в том числе в обиходных словах: двухгодичный, двухкамерный, двухместный, двухпроцентный двухтомный, двухцветный.

(2) Форма ДВУ имеет **обобщенное  значение и может задавать определенное качество сложному слову** (становится возможной  замена близким синонимом): двусмысленный (неоднозначный), двужильный человек  (выносливый),   двуличный человек (лицемер).

Форма ДВУ **характерна для книжной  речи, а также встречается  в терминах**, применяемых в различных областях техники, науки и искусства: двуглавый, двубортный, двуствольный, двузначный двукратный, двучлен, двустишие, двуязычный, двуокись, двуногий.

формы ДВУ и ДВУХ **могут различаться  по смыслу**, при этом слова с прямым значением числительного следует отличать от терминов:  двухлетний ребенок – двулетние растения; двухстворчатая дверь  – класс двустворчатых. При отсутствии четкого  различия  **допускаются обе  формы.**

Comment: Исправила на буквенную запись